# How can i extract a value of a script variable from another website's source code

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Lets just say I am beginner here.

I have this script on one website::

```
<script>    
    var data;   
    var sn = "429d-d51aa-c2ec-df694-6a3gc"; 
    var videoPlayer;    
    var ea = "";    
    showCh("ba185497883dbfe02a43a400410e7960f073d475f3fb8949291de6bd18999cd77");    
.....
.....
```

and the exact same piece of code on another website/URL's source code.
I want to reference the value of variable **sn** and **ShowCh** value (the long alphanumeric string) in my code from the other website's updating values.
*Sorry for my layman language and poor english*

Comment: If you are able to do this, which I doubt, it would be a serious security breach of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the other site almost certainly has CORS restrictions on it, you'll have to bounce the request off your own server.

When your site loads, make a request to your backend. Have the backend do something like:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch('other-website-url')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((result) => {
    const sn = result.match(/ sn = "([^"]+)"/)[1];
    const chParam = result.match(/showCh\*"(\w+)/)[1];
    // Values retrieved; now send sn and chParam to client
  })
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

Then *your* website's frontend can take the response from your server and populate the variables appropriately.